# Nested usercontrol Linkbutton Onclick event not firing after postback - asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using nested controls for a series of forms and having problem with the onclick event.

I'm just using textboxes and a manual code-behind insert rather than Gridview/Details view structure.

The scenario is that I have a car insurance form where users can add additional named drivers.  At the top is a section where you add your own details (which is a seperate user control) and there is a section underneath where you can add up to 4 named drivers (which is also a seperate usercontrol).  What I wanted to do was use my 'Add Driver' linkbutton onclick event to add the details into the database, then clear the form fields so the user could then add another driver. This all works fine until you go to click the Add Driver button again and discover it doesn't work.

This is the Parent control that houses the Add Driver user control:

```
        <h2>Add Permanent Driver</h2>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="uxValidationSummary" runat="server" ShowSummary="true" ValidationGroup="ChangeDetails" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <h3>
        Please enter your details below as they are on your insurance documents</h3>

    <uc1:UserDetails ID="uxUserDetails" runat="server" />

    <uc2:AddDriver ID="uxAddDriver" EntryType="Permanent" runat="server" />
```

This is a cutdown version of the onclick event for the Add Driver submit button on the AddDriver control

```
protected void uxSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate("AddDriver");
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            DriverDAL.DriverTableAdapters.DriverTableAdapter taDriver = new DriverDAL.DriverTableAdapters.DriverTableAdapter();
            taDriver.DriverInsert(StartDate, EndDate, Title,
                FirstName, Surname, DateOfBirth, Gender);

            uxDriverList.DataBind();

            uxDate.Text = string.Empty;
            uxEndDate.Text = string.Empty;
            uxTitle.SelectedIndex = 0;
            uxFirstName.Text = string.Empty; 
            uxSurname.Text = string.Empty;
            uxDateOfBirth.Text = string.Empty;
            uxGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }   
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to reactivate this linkbutton after the first OnClick (or remove it and recreate it) so I can add multiple drivers?  I tried to databind the button after the submit, but as expected, that had no effect, but that is the kind of thing I'm looking for.  I can't redirect the page, because as mentioned earlier in the post, it is using nested controls and I arrive at this form by using the SelectedIndexChanged event of a DropDownList.

Any ideas appreciated - thanks.  Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Does the button still cause a postback, or does it not do anything? Have you tried setting `CausesValidation="false"`?

Comment: Hi James - good idea.  It wasn't causing a postback, but I've set  `CausesValidation = "false"` and it does work.  Only trouble is, I need it to cause validation, so it's not quite solved yet.  That's great though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have some validation that's preventing the button from doing a postback. Try setting `CausesValidation="false"` and see if that makes a difference.

If validation is causing the problem, I would either separate the validation into groups and assign the button to a specific group, or toggle the enabled state of the validators based on some condition, for example:

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = Panel1.Visible;
```

Comment: Hi James - you were absolutely right.  I had validators that were disabled by javascript if the fields were hidden, but they were still failing validation server side.  I added a bit of code in the onclick event to find out which validator was failing and disable them manually if the right criteria was met.  Thanks for your help